# How do I read a signed cookie in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, sinatra

I have mounted Sinatra over Rails. I am able to read normal cookies set by Rails in Sinatra using 'sinatra/cookies'.

However, I am not able to read the signed cookies as possible in rails

```
cookies.signed[:something]
```

It says that signed is undefined.

Also, I tried the below config in my Sinatra, but it didn't help.

```
use Rack::Config do |env| do
  env[ActionDispatch::Cookies::TOKEN_KEY] = Rails.application.config.secret_token
end
use ActionDispatch::Cookies
use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, key: '_myapp_session'
```

Comment: I still have no clue how to achieve this. I ended up using session. You can share sessions using above approach.